# Comparar campo con campo de otra tabla SQL

Tags: sql, join

estoy tratando de resolver algo de un ejercicio de SQL

tengo la tabla A con el campo numero con los registros 1 2 3

y la tabla B con campo numero y registros 2 2 3

Necesito comparar si el primer registro de A es mayor a el primer registro de B, luego comparar el segundo de A con el segundo registro de B y asi sucesivamente, tienen un id con el que hago el join a las tablas pero no se como realizar la comparacion y saber cuando algun registro de A es mayor a el de B

Comment: Hola @MarcoMedina, ya sabes que tienes que intentar algo para que identifiquemos en qué podemos ayudarte. Se trata de enseñarte a pescar, no de darte peces. Pásanos el dataset para generar las tablas, los IDs y el resultado que esperas. Entones, será un placer ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Al join que ya tienes agregale el and donde comparas que uno es mayor al otro. Si no te sale, muestranos que tienes y veremos